# Can I invoke a maven plugin from gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am working on a maven plugin for a tool (integrating it into maven)  and gradle next.

Is it necessary? Is it possible to call from gradle a maven plugin to save me the effort of another plugin? Or do I need a cradle-plugin?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you can't call a Maven plugin from gradle.

Comment: Ok. thanks! I will work on it then!